# Remaining particles after making coffee or tea

Tags: meaning, synonyms

When we make coffee or tea, there are particles that remain at the bottom of the jar.

Is it right to call them 'rudiments' or is there another term for this?

Comment: At the bottom of the jar? Or the bottom of the pot? I think the word you are looking for is [_dregs_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dregs), and I think the site you are looking for is [ell.SE].

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for that input. As a matter of fact, the page your link opens up also uses the word residue and the availability of multiple synonyms makes me think if this is a matter of choice rather than a rule.

Comment: Yes, it's rare in English that there's just _one_ word for something so common.

Comment: Re @J.R.'s comment, you take coffee or tea out of a jar (or tin or packet or box or whatever) before making it. So do you want to know what to call the stuff at the bottom of your cup _after_ you make it when it's wet and in your cup or pot? Actually one can say 'tea leaves' or 'coffee grounds' for both before and after, but one usually says 'tea leaves' for afterwards when 'reading' them. I don't know if people say or do 'reading coffee grounds'. You definitely don't say 'reading dregs'. But if you're just referring to the crud at bottom of your cup, then 'dregs' is the word.

Comment: @Mitch Well said. Yes, I meant the substance that remains **after** a cup of coffee or tea is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Residuum***

re·sid·u·um  [ri-zij-oo-uhm]  Show IPA
noun, plural re·sid·u·a  [-zij-oo-uh]  Show IPA .

> 1.
>   the residue, remainder, or rest of something.
>
> 2.
>   Also, residue. Chemistry . a quantity or body of matter remaining after evaporation, combustion, distillation, etc.
>
> 3.
>   any residual product.

In Deutsch it is called ***kaffeesatz*** as in ***kaffeesatz lesen*** or the Turkish tradition of reading tea leaves.

Comment: **kaffeesatz** *ger*. translates to 'coffee grounds' (particles of ground coffee?), not necessarily the 'left overs'. And oh, yes, '*satz*' also means 'dregs' as a secondary meaning.

Comment: No one, not even the most clinical of people, would actually use this word in speech. It sounds like something a really uptight scientist might use in a technical paper.

Comment: @Mitch not even, us uptight scientist types refer to _residue_ or, at worst, _sediment_ or _precipitate_. Can't speak for MDs though, they have their own language.

Comment: @Kris: Lots of people who call the leftover stuff *coffee grounds* would never use that word for ground coffee. So I think that *Kaffeesatz* is really the word for the leftover stuff. And this is confirmed by [deutsches Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kaffeesatz).

Answer (score 9):

**[dregs](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dregs)** [drɛgz] *pl n*
**1**. (Miscellaneous Technologies / Brewing) (Cookery) solid particles that tend to settle at the bottom of some liquids, such as wine or coffee
**2**. residue or remains

meta: search for the words "coffee OR tea particles remain at the bottom" in Google and you will see the first dictionary result is the TFD entry above! :)

Answer (score 1):

" Sediment " should be the close one ..

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! I like this answer and I have upvoted it but you should add a dictionary definition showing your answer is right. At the moment it has been flagged as low-quality because it is so short. Answers here require a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a simple, single answer.  *Dregs* is the best answer but refers also to the liquid residue (in the sense of "last remaining part" [(M-W:3)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dregs), while *residuum* is a nice word but not appropriate in normal writing (*residue* would be better but not really specific enough).  For coffee there's *grounds* and for tea there's *leaves*, but both of these refer to the product before as well as after the water was added (though with context, e.g. "pour gently leaving the grounds behind" would of course make sense).  *Settlings* may be useable for the particles making up the mud at the bottom of coarsely-filtered coffee.

Comment: I've always interpreted "dregs" to mean a mixture of liquid and solids at the bottom of a pot or cup.

Comment: @HotLicks yes but in any proportion, so anything from a liquid that suddenly feels grainy as you drink it to wet particles

Answer (score 0):

For *coffee*, in my part of the U.S., at least, what is left after brewing is called *coffee grounds*. I have never heard anybody use *coffee grounds* for *ground coffee*, which is what I would call the stuff you start with.

This is confirmed by at least one dictionary, [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grounds):

> 1 b (2): ground coffee beans after brewing.

Googling, however, I see that some people on the West Coast, at least, call unused coffee beans that have been ground *coffee grounds*. So to disambiguate, you could call them *used coffee grounds*.

Answer (score -1):

Er… I don’t think anyone has actually answered the question, as such.

A “rudimentary bow” (for example) is something that is not quite a proper bow, but still manages to make arrows fly.   “primitive”.

The rudiments of some area of knowledge or praxis — (e.g.) management, or book-binding — is the *foundational* knowledge and/or art.   Slang:  AREA“101” (from the codes for first-year university subjects).

(I know this already, but I checked in my Apple “Dictionary”, just to make sure.)

Comment: And how is this an answer to the question? :)